# Return type of constructor signature must be assignable on angular services

Tags: angular

Hello I'm working on MEAN stack project and I want to connect My UI (angularJs 9) with my sever API (nodeJs) for that I've created a service, but when I try to get data I found an ERROR

> Return type of constructor signature must be assignable to the instance type of the class.

on my method return and

> Cannot find name 'get1allCollections'. Did you mean 'HTMLAllCollection'?

on the method declaration.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TransportorService {
  uri = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 


    get1allCollections(){
      return this.http.get(`${this.uri}/collect/get1`);
    }
    getCol(){
      const selector = {
        selector: 'all'
      }
      return this.http.post(`${this.uri}/collect/get`,selector);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try defining your methods outside your constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the functions outside of the constructor:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 

}
get1allCollections(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.uri}/collect/get1`);
}
getCol(){
    const selector = {
        selector: 'all'
    }
    return this.http.post(`${this.uri}/collect/get`,selector);
}
```